# Loading bitmaps in onCreate makes activity start slow

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm new to android programming and recently been learning to develop some applications. It wasn't much problem until I came across dealing with images. I'm trying to develop a simple application more like a eBook which shows pictures(JPEG/PNG) stored in the drawable folder.

My first approach was to use the Gallery widget, but I was unable to implement a proper zoom with that. So I'm now using a simple Imageview to display a single bitmap at a time and change or zoom the bitmap on touch events. In order to do that, I had to decode all the bitmaps into a bitmap array during activity startup so that i could use them anytime.

My application starts fine on my Galaxy Tab but every phone except that takes about 3-5 seconds to start. I just wanted to know if there's an easy way to load bitmaps during start. Forgive me if my question is asked already, but I searched stackoverflow a lot and couldn't find specific answer to my question. Here's my code. Hope anyone could help.

```
    package ....

    imports ....

    public class ImageViewFlipper extends Activity {

    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private Bitmap[] bMap= new Bitmap[15];
    private TextView currentpage;
    private ImageViewZoom iv;
    private imagenum=3;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bMap[0] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page);
    bMap[1] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page1);
    bMap[2] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page10);
    bMap[3] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page11);
    bMap[4] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page12);
    bMap[5] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page13);
    bMap[6] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page14);
    bMap[7] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page2);
    bMap[8] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page3);
    bMap[9] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page4);
    bMap[10] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page5);
    bMap[11] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page6);
    bMap[12] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page7);
    bMap[13] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page8);
    bMap[14] =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.page9);

    currentpage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    iv = (ImageViewZoom) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    iv.setImageBitmapReset( bMap[imagenum], 0, true );
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    ......
```

the value of imagenum changes according to the onFling method, ImageViewZoom is the custom ImageView class. I hope this much  information is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving all the bitmap loading into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that you start inside onCreate. Design your activity to display something sensible before all the images are loaded. The AsyncTask can either load all the images and deliver them in `onPostExecute`, or else can deliver each one as it is loaded using `onProgressUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try loading 2 or 3 images first and then load the other images later in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about Service for loading image in background.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html